How to do file operations on files and directories located in a long UNC network path C#
I have a program that copies large amounts of data from a network drive location to local storage. It has been working fine until recently I tried it on data in a long UNC path that exceeds the windows 260 character limit. Something like this:
\server\data\folder\longfoldernaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaame\
Any sort of file operations don't work correctly because of the path length. e.g.
if (!Directory.Exists(fullpath))
                return;

Will always say the directory doesn't exist when it does. It will also fail to read files in the directory.
I know on local drives you can add the prefix \\?\ to the path to get be able to use long paths in file operations. Is there any sort of long path options for network drives UNC format? Or is there another way around this. Shortening the directory names is not an option. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question? (one answer has an example that calls the windows api, and another states, "For a share folder \ServerName\PathThatIsVeryLong, we could use \?\UNC\ServerName\PathThatIsVeryLong"): how-to-deal-with-files-with-a-name-longer-than-259-characters
